# Mount Optane NVMe SSD for data recovery

Tags: filesystems, mount, data-recovery, ntfs, nvme

Environment:

```
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMmds+.        shawn@shawn-P67A-UD5-B3 
MMm----::-://////////////oymNMd+`     ----------------------- 
MMd      /++                -sNMd:    OS: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina x86_64 
MMNso/`  dMM    `.::-. .-::.` .hMN:   Host: P67A-UD5-B3 
ddddMMh  dMM   :hNMNMNhNMNMNh: `NMm   Kernel: 4.15.0-54-generic 
    NMm  dMM  .NMN/-+MMM+-/NMN` dMM   Uptime: 13 mins 
    NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   Packages: 2107 
    NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
    NMm  dMM  .mmd  `mmm   yMM. dMM   Resolution: 1600x900 
    NMm  dMM`  ..`   ...   ydm. dMM   DE: Cinnamon 4.2.4 
    hMM- +MMd/-------...-:sdds  dMM   WM: Mutter (Muffin) 
    -NMm- :hNMNNNmdddddddddy/`  dMM   WM Theme: Mint-Y-Dark (Mint-Y) 
     -dMNs-``-::::-------.``    dMM   Theme: Mint-Y [GTK2/3] 
      `/dMNmy+/:-------------:/yMMM   Icons: Mint-Y [GTK2/3] 
         ./ydNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   Terminal: gnome-terminal 
            .MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM      CPU: Intel i5-2500K (4) @ 3.700GHz 
                                      GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 
                                      Memory: 1217MiB / 16024MiB
```

I have an Intel Optane H10 NVMe SSD plugged into a PCI NVMe adapter card:

[image]

This does seem to somewhat work as it is seeing the Windows partition:

```
shawn@shawn-P67A-UD5-B3:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0           2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda           8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0  53.1G  0 part /
├─sda2        8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5        8:5    0  11.2G  0 part [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 475.7G  0 part <------
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   980M  0 part
```

[image]

I understand the architecture of the Optane so I don't need that explained. I realize none of this should work at all. But since it is seeing the partitions I figured there might be a slight chance for at least reading the data. I don't care about actually using it. I need to at least read the data off as this is for data recovery for a customer.

This is what I get when I try to manually mount the nvme0n1p3 partition:

```
shawn@shawn-P67A-UD5-B3:/mnt$ sudo mount.ntfs-3g /dev/nvme0n1p3 optane
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
Index buffer (VCN 0x0) of directory inode 0x5 has a size (24) differing from the directory specified size (4096).
Failed to open $Secure: No such file or directory
Failed to mount '/dev/nvme0n1p3': No such file or directory
```

The partition seems "readable" with `dd`:

```
shawn@shawn-P67A-UD5-B3:/mnt$ sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p3 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0279282 s, 375 MB/s
```

I'm guessing a fix could be to "fix" the file system but I need to make 100% that would work as I don't want to obliterate the data on it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whatever you're trying, you shouldn't try it directly: do a verbatim copy and work on the copy.

Comment: @A.B You are right... I'll do that now...

Comment: Is it hibernated? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation or are drives set to RAID/Intel RST and need to be AHCI? Can you mount Read/Only? `mkdir /media/win` and 
`sudo ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/nvme0n1p3 /media/win`